# Why are all JSON posts forbidden in Sails 1.0.0?

Tags: sails.js

I'm using Sails v1.0.0-45. With mostly default settings and Blueprint enabled I am able to create instances of the model I created using query params, but not using JSON. In fact, all JSON POST requests are forbidden. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was CSRF protection.

I would really love it if Sails had posted something to the console so I could tell what was going on with the 403 responses I was getting.

I solved the problem by mounting security/grant-csrf-token so I could send a GET request there and get a token, then I included the token with my JSON body posting to the blueprint api url that would create a new instance.

"_csrf": "[token]"

Comment: I have created [a pull request to sails-docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/pull/972) regarding this